# как сделать программу в full screen Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport {
    public static Stage stage;
    @Value("${windowTitle:JavaFX приложение}")//
    private String windowTitle;

    @Qualifier("mainView")
    @Autowired
    private ControllersConfiguration.ViewHolder view;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle(windowTitle);
        Application.stage.setScene(new Scene(view.getView()));
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launchApp(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Есть ли способ сделать в javafx всё приложение в полноэкранном режиме?
проблема заключается в том, что когда вызываю смену сцены  `Application.stage.setScene(scene);` полноэкранный режим слетает.

Comment: пробуйте выставлять флаг stage.setFullScreen(true); перед вызовом окна. Также инициализируйте сцену в стадии до ее вызова, а не конкретно создавайте бесполезный экземпляр, т.е. stage.setScene(scene)